# How can I run a cmd command in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to run a cmd command in delphi and have tried

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'runas', 'cmd.exe', ' net start ExportFileMainService', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

but it doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @william Don't ever call ShellExecute. It can't report errors properly. Use ShellExecuteEx. Then check for errors as described in the documentation. Beyond that you need to read about the syntax for arguments to cmd. If you read its documentation you will see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You need to specify the `/c` or `/k` command line parameter when invoking `cmd.exe` to run commands (see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)). But `net.exe` is its own app, so you don't need to use `cmd.exe` to run `net` commands. But in this particular case, why are you using `ShellExecute()` at all to start a service instead of using [`StartService()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicew)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is some code I wrote in Delphi 2010 to open a command prompt :

```
function TForm7.RunCmdAndWait(hWnd: HWND; aParameters: string):
    Cardinal;
var
  sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
  aFile, dir: string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  dir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  SetCurrentDir(dir);
  FillChar(sei, SizeOf(sei), 0);
  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
  sei.Wnd := hWnd;
  sei.fMask := {SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI or} SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  sei.lpVerb := 'open';
  aFile := 'cmd';
  sei.lpFile := PChar(aFile);
  sei.lpParameters := PChar(aParameters);
  sei.lpDirectory := PChar(dir);
  sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if not ShellExecuteEx(@sei) then
  begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
  if sei.hProcess <> 0 then
  begin
    while WaitForSingleObject(sei.hProcess, 250) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    GetExitCodeProcess(sei.hProcess, Result);
    CloseHandle(sei.hProcess);
  end else
    TaskMessageDlg('Error running program!', 'No handle to process.',
      mtError, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

Comment: Ho ndoes this answer the specifics of this question?